# Flexboxes in GitHub README.md for profile

Tags: css, github, markdown, readme

When I preview my file in Visual Studio Code it prints out correctly, but when I go to GitHub and look at the presentation, it moves the 2 columns to the same row and the styles section of the Markdown just displays it in plain-text.

You can see the changes itself on my profile: https://github.com/sfgoodwiniii

And the README repo: https://github.com/sfgoodwiniii/sfgoodwiniii

Comment: So to make it clear enough with my intent, I would like a Title and Subtitle centered, and below it having 2 columns (40% and 60% width) where I can put the icon stuff in Column 1 and the statistics stuff in Column 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use CSS in GitHub markdown as it is a part of the sanitization process.

> The HTML is sanitized, aggressively removing things that could harm
> you and your kin—such as script tags, inline-styles, and class or id
> attributes.

[Source](https://github.com/github/markup)